# How to import RDF file to Apache Solr

Tags: solr, rdf

I'm new to Apache Solr.
I want to import a rdf file into solr for indexing.I have googled it but  I didn't find anything useful.
please give me some pointers.

Answer (score 3):

Solr accepts JSON documents. You can transform your RDF document into a [JSON-LD](http://json-ld.org/) document. JSON-LD is a RDF serialization format and it is part of RDF 1.1. You can safely go back and forth between JSON-LD and other RDF serializations and not loose any data.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [HttpDataSource example](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#HttpDataSource_Example) of DataImportHandler. It talks about processing RDF using XPathEntityProcessor.

Edit - Another blog - [RDF Aggregates and Full Text Search on Steroids with Solr](http://fgiasson.com/blog/index.php/2009/04/29/rdf-aggregates-and-full-text-search-on-steroids-with-solr/)

Answer (score 0):

You can also look for [Siren](http://rdelbru.github.io/SIREn/) that has the capability of adding RDF data to lucene

Answer (score -1):

My 2 cents on this experiment, let me know what you think about: http://andreagazzarini.blogspot.it/2014/12/a-solr-rdf-store-and-sparql-endpoint-in.html