# How can I add RDF result from opencalais into apache solr for better search result in my Drupal site?

Tags: drupal, solr, indexing, rdf, opencalais

Add RDF result from opencalais into apache solr for Indexing. I am using solr search integration module's development version(solr 4.x), Opencalais module and Drupal 7. Currently Indexing from taxonomy fields generated by opencalais.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15140691/how-to-import-rdf-file-to-apache-solr

Answer (score 1):

You will want to store the RDF into a separate storage system called a triple store. Check out Apache Jena TDB, an open source option: http://jena.apache.org/documentation/tdb/index.html